# To fit a curve , the plot is in LogLinearPlot. I am trying to fit an equation for this curve

Tags: fitting

```
ks = {0.01, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
   800, 1*^3, 2*^3, 4*^3, 5*^3, 10*^3, 15*^3, 20*^3, 30*^3, 40*^3, 
   70*^3, 1*^5, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12};
aa={15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.708,15.9633,17.5533,18.8007,18.9791,18.9791,18.9791}
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{ks[[i]], aa[[i]]}, {i, 30}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Above are the data I am having, but the problem is my x-axis is in logarithmic scale and my y-axis is in linear scale. Now I have to fit an equation which mimic this curve. I checked NonLinearMoedlFit, But I did not understand it properly. How to extract the equation using the nonlinear model fit function?

Comment: `Table[{ks[[i]], aa[[i]]}, {i, 30}]` can be simplified to `Transpose[{ks, aa}]` or `Thread[{ks, aa}]`

Answer (score 2):

Very large dynamic ranges with many points crowded together at one end and vast spaces between points at the other end seem to often confuse fit routines. So let's work with the log of your horizontal axis to get the fit and then you can transform that back to your original range afterwards if you really need to.

```
lst = N[Table[{Log10[ks[[i]]], aa[[i]]}, {i, 30}]];
model = a E^(b (x - c))/(E^(b (x - c)) + 1) + d;
ff = FindFit[lst, model, {a, b, c, d}, x];
Show[ListPlot[lst],Plot[model/.ff, {x,-2,12}], PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Doesn't look like a bad fit and it didn't need any fiddling or conditions on the variables to get that to work.

And your fitted sigmoid is

```
18.9969-(3.28698 E^(-13.5137(-4.82318+x)))/(1+E^(-13.5137(-4.82318+x)))
```

Comment: Bill  can you explain little extra, I am kind of not understood what you did.  I take your answer , thanks. but some information about how you solved help me alot.

Comment: There are far smaller distances between .01 and 1 and 2 and ... than there are between 1*^6 and 1*^8 and 1*^12. That can confuse Fit. So I used Log10[x] to more evenly space the points and not confuse Fit. Then I picked a Sigmoid function because your plot looked like a Sigmoid. There are lots of those functions, look in Wiki, I just picked one. The parameters determine the lower limit, upper limit, where the "middle" is and how steep it is in the middle. Those are the a,b,c,d that we want Fit to find. Then we give Fit your data, the sigmoid with unknown variables and ask it to find the best.

Comment: Look up each of the functions I used in the help system. And click on the "Details" on each help page to find more information. Study what each function is supposed to do. /. is a function which is also called ReplaceAll. Study it in the help pages. Try to understand why I would use each function where I did. Look at each value I assigned to a variable and try to understand how that value was calculated. If you have more specific questions then please ask.

Comment: Bill can  we fit the bode plot for only the slope part of the plot. I mean excluding the horizontal  line in the plot.

Comment: You could try fitting a line to the three points that lie on the sharply increasing part of your data. `ks = {30*^3, 40*^3, 70*^3}; aa = {15.9633, 17.5533, 18.8007}; lst = N[Table[{Log10[ ks[[i]]], aa[[i]]}, {i, 3}]]; model = m*x + b; ff = FindFit[lst, model, {m, b}, x]; Show[ListPlot[lst], Plot[model /. ff, {x, Log10[30*^3], Log10[70*^3]}], PlotRange -> All]`